# Why are reports of LGBT hate crimes rising in the west?

Tags: crime, western-world, lgbt+, hate-speech

Sources [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-bristol-62413792), [Security.Org](https://www.security.org/resources/anti-lgbt-hate-crime-stats/). This rise seems to happen in US, France, and also Germany. Could an explanation be given for what the reason behind this rise is?

Comment: The linked articles give explanations. Are you not satisfied with them?

Comment: Do they really? I went through them myself again, and they don't give any narrative on why the hate crimes have risen. @Trilarion

Comment: Have the hate crimes risen, or has *reporting* of hate crimes risen?

Comment: This does not appear to be about politics but about the motivations of people committing crimes. Though it could also be an issue of more incidents getting reported as well.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to speculate on possible answers. If you would like to answer, please do your research, make sure your facts check out, and then post a proper answer. Although I doubt that it is really possible to find a definitive answer to a question like that. Individual causes for large-scale sociopolitical developments are usually very hard to isolate.